# How to get the value of a checkbox in PHP

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I'm having problem in getting the value of a checkbox when checking the value first in DB then change to POST value after submitting the form. Here's my sample:

1: I need to check first in my db if it's need to be checked or not.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="chckbox" <?=$value['chckbox'] == 'ok' ? 'checked' : ''?> />
<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" />
</form>
```

2: Then if I already check in DB I want to get the POST value of checkbox after submitting the form if it is checked or not.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="chckbox" <?=isset($_POST['chckbox']) ? 'checked' : ''?> />
<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" />
</form>
```

My question is... how to combined my two sample when I'm updating the form?
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chckbox" <?php echo $value['chckbox'] == 'ok' || isset($_POST['chckbox']) ? 'checked' : '' ?> >
```

After submitting the form,

```
<?php
$checked = $value['chckbox'] == 'ok'?'checked':'';
if(isset($_POST['chckbox']) && $_POST['chckbox']=='on'){
    $checked = "checked";       
}elseif(count($_POST)>0 && !isset($_POST['chckbox'])){
    $checked = "";      
}
 ?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="chckbox" value="on"  <?php echo $checked; ?> >
```

Comment: It didn't work when I unchecked the checkbox and submit the form the checkbox still checked

Comment: because of your `$value['chckbox']` is ok that is the reason

Comment: yeah that's the problem how can I break the condition of $value['chckbox'] == ok after submitting the form? any idea?

Comment: @user1157768, I have updated my answer, please check!

Comment: It's working now! Thank you! is there any simplification for this? because I have a lot of checkbox that I need to validate like this..

Comment: Make it as function and recall it where ever you want

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="code" value="'.$row['Code'].'">
<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" />
</form>
```

php:

```
$Code=$_REQUEST['code'];
```